# Angular4 Form Builder dynamic

Tags: angular

I'm working on an Angular(4) on Rails app, and trying to finish my CRUD functionality. I'm stuck on how to handle an 'edit' in terms of front-end.

I've tested the logic by manually `PUT`ting when a button is clicked, but I'm struggling to get the form to pre-populate.

**The proposed flow**

- User clicks `Clients` which performs a `getClients()` function.
- `Clients` page has a clickable `ID` for each client to go to the `clients/:id` page.
- `clients/:id` performs a `getClientById()` function passing in `params['id']`
- Form is pre-populated with the information
- When submitted `editClientById` is ran

**My Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-client-index',
  templateUrl: './client-index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client-index.component.sass']
})
export class ClientIndexComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private clientService: ClientService,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }
  public indexForm: FormGroup;
  public submitted: boolean;
  public events: any[] = [];
  client = Client;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      let id = params['id'];
      this.clientService.getClientById(params['id']);
      this.indexForm = new FormGroup({
        name: ['', <any>Validators.required],
        status: [''],
        logo: ['']
    });
    }
  }


  edit(model: Client,  isValid: boolean) {
    this.submitted = true;

    console.log(model, isValid);
  }



  // demo(){
  //   console.log('pressed');
  //   this.clientService.editClientById({
  //     'id': 4,
  //     'name': 'Demo User2222',
  //     'status': 'This',
  //     'logo': "Test"
  //   })
  // }

}
```

**Service**

```
  getClientById(id): Observable<Client> {
    return this.authToken.get('clients/' + id)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }


  editClientById(client:any): Observable<Client> {
    return this.authToken.patch('clients/' + client.id, client)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }
```

The current `ngOnInit` function is what I'm trying based on a couple SO articles and Scotch tutorials I've seen. So far the closest I have gotten was my Submit button `patch`ing to the API, but it did not pre-populate the field.

My current setup, it is not working at all.
I'm wondering if it's because my `getClientById` is running before the ngOnInit is finished loading, or if it's functioning at all.

I believe I need to bind to the model, somehow, but unsure how.

Comment: Why did you expect the form to be populated? You don't wait for the request to finish (or subscribe to trigger it) and explicitly set the form to be empty.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's a completely fair point, and essentially where I'm having issues. If I do something to the effect of `status: [this.client.status]` I will get a property error, which is what made me think it was due to loading rate.

Comment: Why would the loading rate matter? You *never* assign anything to `this.client`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to subscribe to the result of calling getClientById on your service, then take the result and use patchValue to put the retrieved client object's fields into your form fields.

Build for form first, then subscribe to the result of your service call:

e.g. (just typed this, not tested...)

```
this.indexForm = new FormGroup({
        name: ['', <any>Validators.required],
        status: [''],
        logo: ['']
);
this.clientService.getClientById(params['id']).subscribe(client => {
    this.indexForm.patchValue({
 name: client.name,
 status: client.status,
 logo: client.logo
});
```

Comment: This answer did help me figure out the proper path, albeit the code wasn't correct so I appreciate it. patchValue on promise was my perfect need.